# Getting error while creating Alert rule in Log Analytics in OMS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, oms

When I tried to `add alert rule using OMS portal - Log analytics`.

getting below error -

Search resulted in an error of type: SyntaxError

query is `Type=Event EventLevelName=error`

query is `correct still getting above error` can any one check this.

Getting error while creating Alert rule in Log Analytics in OMS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Event | where EventLevelName == "Error"`.

[image]

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-solutions-resources-searches-alerts#log-analytics-api-version).

```
Workspace version   API version Sample query
v1 (legacy) 2015-11-01-preview  Type=Event EventLevelName = Error
v2 (upgraded)   2017-03-15-preview  Event | where EventLevelName == "Error"
```